# Rating system limited at 10

Tags: python, rating

I use this system to make 20 groups with the numbers 1-20, then rates each group to see how well it has randomised e.g. (1,1,1,1)=1 since there is only one type of number, where as (1,2,3,3)=3 since there are 3 different numbers. This code works with smaller number and ranks them. However when i get to 20, even though my groups state there are more than 10 different numbers, the rating system maxes out at 10? Can anyone see why this is to get the rating system maxes out at 10?

```
import numpy
import random
members=20
n_groups =20
participants=list(range(1,members+1))*n_groups
#print participants 
random.shuffle(participants)

with open('myfile1.txt','w') as tf:
    for i in range(n_groups):
        group = participants[i*members:(i+1)*members]
        for participant in group:
            tf.write(str(participant)+' ')
        tf.write('\n')

with open('myfile1.txt','r') as tf:
    g = [list(map(int, line.split())) for line in tf.readlines()]
    print(g)


my_groups =g

def get_rating(group):
    """
    (tuple of ints)->int
    """
    group_str = ""
    for each_num in group:
        group_str += str(each_num)
    return len(set(group_str))

for each_grp in my_groups:  
    print(get_rating(each_grp))
```

Output:
    [[6, 11, 11, 7, 16, 3, 1, 11, 10, 16, 14, 15, 14, 20, 15, 12, 1, 12, 15, 1], [15, 5, 7, 6, 9, 11, 3, 1, 5, 17, 9, 19, 10, 1, 20, 18, 3, 2, 5, 18], [20, 11, 1, 18, 5, 5, 2, 4, 14, 10, 18, 1, 7, 17, 9, 11, 14, 16, 3, 12], [19, 13, 1, 16, 16, 14, 7, 6, 5, 11, 19, 1, 14, 20, 2, 12, 5, 19, 8, 4], [4, 5, 10, 18, 10, 16, 13, 12, 5, 19, 10, 16, 3, 2, 10, 4, 2, 17, 2, 8], [19, 9, 8, 5, 1, 3, 8, 11, 18, 20, 19, 15, 6, 15, 15, 2, 8, 7, 6, 18], [4, 2, 3, 8, 2, 18, 13, 14, 14, 3, 8, 12, 10, 17, 9, 19, 10, 20, 13, 2], [4, 9, 17, 20, 12, 2, 10, 6, 6, 19, 3, 17, 6, 2, 2, 8, 14, 3, 6, 6], [9, 16, 5, 3, 9, 16, 11, 4, 13, 13, 20, 20, 17, 19, 18, 12, 15, 13, 14, 16], [11, 16, 9, 18, 5, 3, 13, 19, 16, 12, 7, 7, 20, 10, 12, 13, 20, 17, 4, 10], [20, 5, 3, 11, 15, 4, 15, 11, 10, 13, 14, 2, 17, 14, 9, 9, 14, 6, 4, 13], [4, 7, 19, 15, 19, 13, 11, 1, 4, 15, 18, 10, 2, 10, 1, 8, 4, 8, 9, 7], [10, 10, 6, 1, 16, 1, 11, 18, 17, 9, 16, 12, 16, 11, 11, 1, 18, 19, 4, 13], [12, 13, 19, 7, 5, 8, 20, 15, 17, 14, 8, 8, 13, 8, 12, 4, 18, 2, 20, 7], [8, 5, 12, 2, 12, 5, 6, 12, 14, 9, 19, 1, 18, 17, 16, 10, 16, 5, 3, 4], [4, 3, 13, 7, 3, 4, 5, 6, 5, 5, 7, 4, 1, 12, 17, 1, 15, 6, 18, 9], [9, 15, 3, 17, 20, 14, 8, 12, 3, 14, 13, 8, 6, 1, 15, 9, 19, 12, 18, 3], [7, 7, 14, 3, 11, 14, 20, 17, 6, 11, 17, 2, 9, 9, 17, 14, 2, 16, 7, 11], [13, 8, 4, 15, 8, 16, 13, 19, 19, 18, 6, 15, 18, 17, 16, 20, 20, 7, 9, 10], [17, 15, 2, 7, 7, 7, 13, 20, 8, 6, 10, 17, 1, 12, 15, 20, 6, 18, 19, 11]]
    8
    9
    10
    10
    10
    9
    8
    9
    10
    10
    9
    9
    9
    9
    10
    9
    10
    8
    10
    9

Note: The numbers at the end rate each bracket lower the better, however seems     to max out at 10 even though if I count some have more manually

The other system:
    import numpy
    import random
    members=20
    n_groups =20
    participants=list(range(1,members+1))*n_groups
    #print participants 
    random.shuffle(participants)

```
with open('myfile1.txt','w') as tf:
    for i in range(n_groups):
        group = participants[i*members:(i+1)*members]
        for participant in group:
            tf.write(str(participant)+' ')
        tf.write('\n')

with open('myfile1.txt','r') as tf:
    g = [list(map(int, line.split())) for line in tf.readlines()]
    print(g)


my_groups =g

def get_rating(group):
    return len(set(group))
print(len(set(group)))
```

This returns:
[[11, 9, 8, 3, 2, 13, 7, 17, 7, 2, 3, 2, 17, 8, 5, 4, 6, 12, 1, 16], [3, 4, 7, 5, 17, 16, 16, 20, 1, 5, 16, 5, 4, 11, 11, 4, 20, 15, 8, 12], [6, 3, 15, 14, 5, 17, 1, 10, 13, 10, 4, 20, 5, 15, 17, 6, 9, 17, 13, 6], [11, 5, 11, 20, 2, 2, 10, 6, 18, 13, 6, 16, 18, 16, 7, 2, 3, 8, 11, 15], [18, 15, 8, 1, 16, 16, 14, 3, 19, 14, 1, 17, 12, 6, 4, 3, 3, 12, 12, 20], [19, 16, 12, 2, 15, 8, 8, 18, 20, 6, 13, 1, 13, 19, 8, 16, 17, 8, 3, 20], [9, 5, 11, 18, 1, 16, 18, 10, 16, 17, 4, 2, 2, 5, 5, 7, 8, 5, 10, 3], [18, 4, 9, 11, 9, 9, 14, 1, 4, 19, 17, 10, 12, 18, 8, 13, 5, 14, 12, 17], [20, 13, 4, 7, 13, 10, 1, 2, 6, 11, 7, 9, 13, 10, 7, 14, 6, 8, 9, 17], [14, 13, 15, 14, 14, 20, 2, 19, 2, 13, 13, 6, 8, 10, 7, 12, 9, 8, 17, 19], [1, 12, 10, 20, 5, 15, 4, 3, 19, 16, 13, 1, 6, 10, 2, 6, 17, 1, 5, 19], [7, 7, 13, 8, 11, 9, 12, 13, 2, 16, 18, 19, 4, 12, 8, 15, 9, 13, 2, 17], [20, 18, 15, 11, 14, 8, 4, 3, 4, 16, 4, 14, 19, 19, 6, 11, 7, 2, 13, 14], [9, 14, 18, 7, 17, 15, 5, 9, 12, 18, 19, 1, 20, 12, 10, 3, 10, 6, 18, 10], [10, 10, 7, 7, 3, 11, 10, 20, 15, 16, 17, 5, 20, 12, 9, 20, 2, 7, 18, 1], [19, 5, 5, 19, 11, 3, 15, 1, 9, 19, 19, 1, 11, 7, 16, 3, 8, 12, 20, 11], [8, 2, 18, 15, 18, 14, 19, 8, 5, 10, 16, 20, 4, 14, 7, 6, 18, 17, 6, 3], [4, 9, 2, 6, 15, 16, 17, 14, 12, 19, 16, 2, 12, 3, 9, 17, 9, 7, 19, 11], [20, 5, 4, 19, 1, 4, 11, 15, 13, 15, 11, 14, 14, 11, 7, 9, 12, 9, 10, 3], [1, 14, 20, 6, 6, 15, 12, 1, 4, 15, 15, 1, 13, 18, 14, 20, 3, 18, 10, 18]]
11 <- (only one rate, i want 20)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `get_rating` function is not implemented correctly. For example, consider the output of `get_rating((1, 11))`. Your function concatenates all the numbers together to get `'111'` and returns the number of unique characters (`1`). There are only ten base-10 digits, so that is your maximum.

You can avoid this problem by just simplifying your code:

```
def get_rating(group):
    return len(set(group))
```

There's no need to convert the numbers to strings.

Comment: Yeh i tried this before, however it only rates the last square bracket, rather than all 20? Not sure how to get the best of both

Comment: @zoo-ran: You'll have to clarify what `get_rating` is supposed to do, because my function matches the example outputs you have in your question.

Comment: ok sorry, Is there anyway to make 20 versions for each one of the groups? Ill mark your answer right. Your function works well yeh, however before it rated all the groups, however when i tried your one it rated it correctly but for only one of the groups?

Comment: @zoo-ran: What do you mean by "20 versions for each one of the groups"?

Comment: So the code makes 20 groups, then my version at the top rated each one of these groups. However i substituted yours and it only gave me the rate for the last group:

Comment: @zoo-ran: Running your original code with the substituted function, I see a different number for each group. How are you running the code?

Comment: I have edited question with the new code, I run it like that? (on jupyter python3)

Comment: @zoo-ran: What happened to this part? `for each_grp in my_groups: print(get_rating(each_grp))`